# React Native | View breaks formatting of Text

Tags: css, typescript, react-native, user-interface

[image]

My react native layout breaks in a very wierd way. When I have a Text < View < myComponent < Screen it only shows 2 letters and a blue SVG. What is this and why can't it just be normal, I have absolutely no clue at this point.

When I remove the View or extract the Code directly onto the page it works. Where is the difference? Something is breaking my layout.

App.ts

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <BottomDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Navigation.tsx

```
export const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export function BottomDrawer() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Lookup" component={LookupScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

LookupScreen.tsx

```
export const LookupScreen = () => {
  return <DictEntry />;
};
```

DictEntry.tsx

```
export const DictEntry = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{"description"}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```